# python - How to create a dctionary from a CSV string

Tags: python, csv

I have some comma-separated strings as follows:

```
filename1,12345,ABC
filename2,6789,CDE
filename3,999,GHI
...
etc.
```

I want to build a dictionary from these data, using the first column (a filename) as key and the rest of the data as a list of attributes (which may be size, date of last access, etc.), as

```
{'filename1': ['12345','ABC'], 'filename2': ['6789','CDE'], 'filename3':['999','GHI']}
```

The data do **not** include a header line and each line is a csv-string built in code and not read from a file.

I tried something like this:

```
import csv

s = """
filename1,12345,ABC
filename2,6789,CDE
filename3,999,GHI
"""

reader_list = csv.DictReader(s.splitlines())
for row in reader_list:
    print row
```

which returns this:

```
{None: ['filename1', '12345', 'ABC']}
{None: ['filename2', '6789', 'CDE']}
{None: ['filename3', '999', 'GHI']}
```

but I could not figure a way of creating the key using the filename.

Any hints?

Comment: `final_dict = dict{}`,`for row in reader_list:`,`final_dict[row[None][0]] = row[None][1:]`. But parsing the file yourself would seem a better solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the `csv`module for this:

```
>>> s = """
filename1,12345,ABC
filename2,6789,CDE
filename3,999,GHI
"""
>>> d = {}
>>> for line in s.splitlines():
    if line:
        parts = line.split(',')
        key, attributes = parts[0], parts[1:]
        d[key] = attributes
>>> print d
{'filename1': ['12345', 'ABC'], 'filename2': ['6789', 'CDE'], 'filename3': ['999', 'GHI']}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I need. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You could simplify: `key, *attributes = parts`

Answer (score 5):

Here's a simple solution:

```
import csv

lines = """filename1,12345,ABC
filename2,6789,CDE
filename3,999,GHI"""

dic = {}

for row in csv.reader(lines.split("\n")):
    dic[row[0]] = row[1:]

print(dic)
```

Comment: Also a good solution, although it still requires the csv module.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you can pass in the field names:

```
reader_list = csv.DictReader(s.splitlines(), ('filename', 'number', 'thing'))
```

Then you can use those keys

Answer (score 0):

You can use dictionary comprehension:

```
import csv
final_dict = {i:i[1:] for i in csv.reader(open('filename.csv'))}
```